# how to install software through software center?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

Software center don't give option of download or install it just give option to see more info then how can i install software through it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search for a software and click on the result. You will get an option to install it, as shown below. If you click install it will ask for your password and you are good to go!

[image: enter image descriptio here]

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/v/t34.0-12/11275726_659106257523413_2015722370_n.jpg?oh=61cba9be146f7c097abc8fdafabd20a0&oe=557F9174&__gda__=1434441736_78a8389db3ec3793f1c417c4215ac114

i shared the link above is a picture i took from my software center, here it do not give option to download or install, now ??

Comment: Click on `more info` and it will get you to another page. Look for the install button on the right.